# Moodle insert data from select of another table

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I had a look of moodle's [data manipulation API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#insert_record) and I found that I can Insert a value via the `$DB->insert_records` and select via `$DB->get_records_sql` but in my case I have a table named `block_userlist`:

```
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | bigint(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id          | bigint(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logout_time      | bigint(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| login_time       | bigint(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| session_duration | bigint(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I want to populate it from the following fields from the `user` one:

```
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(10)   | NO   | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| currentlogin      | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | 0    |                |
| lastaccess        | bigint(10)   | NO   | MUL | 0    |                |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Like that:

```
block_userlist.user_id <= user.id
block_userlist.login_time <= user.currentlogin
block_userlist.logout_time <= user.lastaccess
block_userlist.session_duration <= user.lastaccess - user.currentlogin
```

Hence I could utilize the `$DB->get_records_sql` via php to retrieve the results and via `$DB->insert_records` insert them back but this would result some roundtrip between website and database whilst many DBMSes could insert values to one table from a select query of another for example in my case if I had mySQL I could do:

```
INSERT INTO block_userlist(user_id,logout_time,login_time,session_duration) SELECT user.id,user.lastaccess,user.currentlogin, (user.lastaccess - user.currentlogin) from user;
```

Therefore I want to ask:

- Is there a way to execute an Insert-select query without the roundtrip to php; or
- Is there a way to create an custom Cross-Db (for any DBMs that moodle supports) query via a custom query builder;

Comment: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#execute ?

Comment: @ChrisWhite 's solution is probably best - if only because the Moodle DDL/DML apis do not support views.  In reality, your "table" that you've created should be a view.  Arguably, if you're only presenting information that's in the user table in the first place, it shouldn't even exist in the first place - just query the user table instead.